# What is the best automated ETL method to transfer data from SQL Server IN cloud (AWS) to SQL Server NOT Cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sql-server, data-extraction

We have 2 SQL Server databases. One of them is to be moved to AWS cloud.

Is Amazon RDS the ONLY approach to move the SQL Server to AWS?

1. What is the best way to automate data transfer of table data from the SQL Server that IS in the cloud to the SQL Server that is NOT in the cloud?
2. The volume and complexity of data is not high in our case. Tables are simple and volume is not high; we need to migrate only ONE table every night. And we'd like to automate it.

Would AWS Glue be useful for this? Would it help in loading data from INSIDE the cloud to OUTSIDE?

Answer (score 0):

*Glue* is an ETL tool, where the T stands for Transform. It may be used but is not optimal for your usecase.

Check out **AWS Database Migration Service (DMS)** - that’s designed exactly for what you need. It can read from on-prem DB, optionally do simple schema transformations, and then write to a db on AWS RDS. It can do one-off and also continuous migration.

Obviously you will need a connectivity (VPN or DirectConnect) from AWS to your source DB.

Hope that helps :)